# how to calling a javascript function from a typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file called general.js.  In the file is a function

```
function fadeDivWrite(pString) {};
```

The typescript file is called Default.ts.  I'm trying to call the fadeDivWrite function from general.js but it's not working.  What i'm trying to use in the Default.ts file is

```
 var pText: string = "Test";
        declare function fadeDivWrite(pText): string;
```

The ts file won't compile with an red line under the declare.  The error is (TS) Modifiers cannot appear here.

This is how I've seen it done in multipal places when doing searches so I'm missing something.  Hoping someone can help out.

thanks
shannon

Comment: `declare` goes in the declaration file general.d.ts. Use `import * as general from './path/to/general'`. Call the method as `general.fadeDivWrite()` in your ts file.

Comment: So just to be clear your problem is with the transpiler? So you don't know if the code itself works should it transpile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, the below should work - it certainly all passes a quick test on the TypeScript Playground.

```
declare function fadeDivWrite(text: string): string;

const pText: string = 'Test';
const result = fadeDivWrite(pText);
```

I have rewritten to avoid any confusion there might be between the type information and the actual variable `pText`.

Let me know if you still have an issue and include the error message if you have one.

Comment: thanks for the response.  So i put that in my ts file.  Now fadeDivWrite has the red line under it telling me "Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.  Would sure appreciate it if your willing to continue helping.

Comment: Ah - it is likely that you have inadvertently included the function in the compilation, as well as the ambient declaration. Are you sure it isn't either a) in a TypeScript file already, or b) are you including JavaScript files in your compilation, so the general.js is part of the compile?

Comment: that was it.. has included a reference to the java script file.  I up voted your answer.  thanks much